# VBA: Reading a list of filenames taking various amounts of time

Tags: vba, excel, time

I have been tasked with creating and updating a series of VBA based excel add-on programs by my superiors at work. One of the programs is a utility that compares the contents of two folders and gives a list of what files are different. Most of the program works very well, but I am having issues with one section of the code; namely, the section that is tasked with gathering all the filenames of the files to be checked.

The section itself does function, most of the time with no issue, but on occasion, it will take inordinate amounts of time. I have been running the tests on the same set of data for the entire development of the utility, so I know that the issue is not the number of files being searched (which is in the hundreds and will eventually be nearly the thousands). My issue is that the section of code is wildly inconsistent with its timing.

The section of code in question is here:

```
Sub GetFileList(ByRef FileSpec() As String, FileArray() As FileInfo, FoldIndex As Integer)
'FileSpec - an array of strings that correspond to the filtered list of file extensions to be searched
'FileArray - an array of strings that will end up holding the complete list of relevant file names
'FoldIndex - an integer that corresponds to which folder is being searched (1 or 2)
'Returns an array of filenames that match FileSpec
'If no matching files are found, returns an error messagebox
'Arbitrarly takes inordinate  amount of time, sometimes upwards of 20 seconds, to finish running.
'Usually when the filtering has been changed.
Dim FileCount As Integer
Dim FileName As String

On Error GoTo NoFilesFound

FileCount = 0
For i = LBound(FileSpec) + 1 To UBound(FileSpec)
    FileName = Dir(FileSpec(i))

'Loop until no more matching files are found
    Do While FileName <> ""
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
        ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To FileCount)
        FileArray(FileCount).FileName = FileName
        FileName = Dir()
        Select Case FoldIndex
            Case 1
                Call FormFunctionality.UpdateResults(FileCount & ": " & FileArray(FileCount).FileName & vbCrLf, "")
            Case 2
                Call FormFunctionality.UpdateResults("", FileCount & ": " & FileArray(FileCount).FileName & vbCrLf)
        End Select
    Loop
Next i
If FileCount = 0 Then GoTo NoFilesFound
Exit Sub

'Error handler
NoFilesFound:
ReDim FileArray(1)
FileArray(1).FileName = "Error"
MsgBox ("Error: No files found of requested type" & vbCrLf & "Please review folders and requested file types.")
End
End Sub

Sub UpdateResults(Str1 As String, Str2 As String)
'Prints strings to the results window text boxes
RbtUtilResultScreen.Folder1Results.Text = RbtUtilResultScreen.Folder1Results.Text & Str1
RbtUtilResultScreen.Folder2Results.Text = RbtUtilResultScreen.Folder2Results.Text & Str2
RbtUtilResultScreen.Folder1Results.SetFocus
RbtUtilResultScreen.Folder2Results.SetFocus
End Sub
```

The Time inconsistency varies wildly. For ~350 files being searched, the average time to generate the list of files is about 2 seconds. Sometimes, that time shoots up to 10 or 20 seconds, which is frankly unacceptable. It gets even worse with more files being searched, and I have had it take up to a minute and thirty seconds for ~800 files (where the average is still something like 3 seconds).

**My question is this:** Is there something obvious that I am doing wrong, or is there a better way to handle reading files in that I have overlooked? What could be causing this inconsistency within the program?

*If more in-depth timing information or other sections of the code are needed, I will provide. I do not believe that I can provide access to the data that I have been running the tests on, though.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paul has suggested in his response that you need to use "fixed step" to re-dimension the array which seems to be one issue.

The other issue seems to be updating the form text continuously to show progress. If it is not too critical then you can think of changing it to something like below.

Declare dictionary object at the beginning of code before Loop.

`Dim objDict As Object
objDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")`

And then modified block would be like shown below.

```
For i = LBound(FileSpec) + 1 To UBound(FileSpec)
    FileName = Dir(FileSpec(i))
    objDict.RemoveAll
    Do While FileName <> ""
        If Not objDict.Exists(FileName) Then objDict.Add FileName, FileName
        FileName = Dir()
    Loop
    Select Case FoldIndex
        Case 1
            Call FormFunctionality.UpdateResults(objDict.Count & ": " & FileName & vbCrLf, "")
        Case 2
            Call FormFunctionality.UpdateResults("", objDict.Count & ": " & FileName & vbCrLf)
    End Select
Next I
```

Test it on a backup!

Comment: I was honestly just starting to think of something similar to this. I just finished testing the setup with the Form Update Results commented out and it seems that the issue has not occurred while the comments are in place. I think its safe to say that the problem is stemming from there.
I will try out your solution and report back after I have tested more.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have fully converted the program over to dictionary based format and it shaved the average time of execution in half. If I had known there were dictionaries in VBA I would have started out there.

Comment: Good to know that it has helped.

Answer (score 1):

A reason is not clear from your code. However, you can optimize some part and maybe that reduces the time. Namely, you `ReDim` on each iteration and this can cause memory management overhead. Instead, `ReDim` a fixed number of items, for example:

```
    Dim nElms As Integer
    ...
    nElms = 0
    FileCount = 0

    Do While FileName <> ""
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
        If (FileCount > nElms) Then
            nElms = nElms + 250
            ReDim Preserve FileArray(1 To nElms)
        EndIf
```